# Bash : Store Date Format in Variable (Self Evaluating Env Variables)

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I want to store formatted date in a variable and want to use that format every time. 
for example :

```
    export MYDATE=$(date +%m%d%Y)
    mkdir myfolder_$MYDATE
```

But in the above case MYDATE is evaluated only once with current date. Instead I want to get the latest date each time I invoke $MYDATE (something like exec everytime). I also tried with

```
     export MYDATE='$(date +%m%d%Y)'
```

but this is not useful.

Again, I don't want to try aliases or bash functions and looking for achieving this using bash environment variables.

Any suggestions or ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use a function:

```
function mydate(){
    date +%m%d%Y
}
```

Then use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) to interpolate the value into a string:

```
mkdir "foo_$(mydate)"
```

Btw, you can make the function available to sub shells using:

```
export -f mydate
```

Imo this is the cleanest way.

Answer (score 1):

In Bash 4.3 (current version) and earlier, an environment variable is computed once, stored as a string (exported or not), then that string is retrieved whenever the variable is referenced. To get an updated string each time, there is no way other than using an alias or a function, which you seem to know about.

A hacky way to update variables would be to do it inside `$PROMPT_COMMAND`, e.g.:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='MYDATE=$(date +%m%d%Y)'
```

However, this would only run each time the prompt is redrawn.

Comment: I agree. I thought if we can use exec or eval statements inside the definition of variable so that it eval's each time when the variable is expanded. something like :   MYDATE='eval $(date +%m%d%Y)'

Comment: I also heard about indirect expansion with bash variables. Not sure if that can be applied here. If not can this be suggested as enhancement to bash ?

Comment: As @chepner suggests, some version is in the works. But why no functions?

Comment: functions sucks. specially when I launch other programs like java, webservers, the function definition breaks in their environment variable display as they are multiline. Instead I prefer to write a script and invoke that.

Comment: What are you doing with functions that a) you are displaying them and b) you care what that display looks like?

Comment: ..."function definition breaks in their environment variable display"? This doesn't make sense: Unless you go out of your way to export them, functions don't exist in the environment at all.

Answer (score 1):

In `bash` 4.4 (not yet released), you'll be able to do something like this:

```
$ mydate="\D{%m%d%Y %T}"
$ echo "${mydate@P}"
08102016 12:22:02
# wait a few seconds
$ echo "${mydate@P}"
08102016 12:22:05
```

When `mydate` is expanded, any prompt escape sequences in the value are expanded as if you displaying a prompt. This doesn't provide a way to execute arbitrary code, but does at least cover the use case in your question.

Comment: This is interesting. Good to hear 4.4 is addressing something related to this. I see 4.4 beta is available for download. will give a try.